# Asymptotic Estimate for $1 - \tau_k$ with $\tau_{0}=0$ and $\tau_{k+1}=e^{-1+\tau_k}$

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

> Consider the following problem:
>   $$\tau_{0}=0\qquad\tau_{k+1}=e^{-1+\tau_k}\qquad f(k)= 1 - \tau_k$$
>   Does $f(k)$ have any asymptotic estimate when $k$ get large, say $k=2^{64}$?

I have run an computer program to compute $f(k)$ for $\log_2(k)\in \{10, 11, \cdots,29\}$, the results shows that $-\log_2(f(k))\sim \log_2(k)-1$. See the figure of $-\log_2(1-\tau_k)$ for $\log_2(k)\in \{10, 11, \cdots,29\}$:

[image]

There is some weird behavior for $-\log_2(1-\tau_k)$ when $\log_2(k)\geq 28$. It stable at the same value for $\log_2(k)\geq 28$. I guess it was because the computer program was written in C++ and there exist some precision problem.

> Could anybody help to provide an asymptotic estimate for $f(k)$ when $k$ get large, say $k \geq 2^{64}$? Any kind of reference would also be appreciated.

PS: I found a paper named *[On the height of trees](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700004432)* in which one can find a precise estimate on the ratio $ \tau_k $ which is as follows,
$$ \tau_k \approx_{k \rightarrow \infty}
  1 - \frac{2}{k} + \frac{2}{3}\frac{\log k}{k^2} + \frac{c}{k^2} + \cdots$$
where $c$ is a certain constant.

It suggests that $ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} k f(k) = 2 $.
Unfortunately, the authors did not provide the proof. It seems that this formula was got by study the regular iteration of real and complex functions.

Comment: Do you have used `log1p(x)` instead of `log(1+x)`? If not you will get severe truncation errors when computing $1-\eta_k$ if $\eta_k$ is small. See here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p.

Comment: I have used `logl(long double x)` and `expl(long double x)` in the program from which I got the result shown in the figure. When I try to use `log1p(long double x)` with intel compiler (/Qstd=c++11), and run the program again, I got an error, it said _"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF5EE2CCFA (libmmd.dll) in TheoreticalFG.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000019."_ I am sorry, I don't know how to deal with this error. @gammatester

Comment: You mean you can compute $$\log(1-10^{-10}) \approx  -1.0000000827903709\times 10^{-10}$$ but get the error message instead of the more precises result $$\mathrm{log1p}(-10^{-10})\approx -1.0000000000499999\times 10^{-10}$$
Of course you have to use $\mathrm{log1p}(-\eta_k)$ to compute $\log(1-\eta_k).$ (But I guess this error is not related to computation, because is contains *access violation*)

Comment: I am sorry, I used `log1p(x)` to compute `log(x)`. I have corrected this now.  Unfortunately, the program still did not work with intel compiler and reported the same error.   I then used g++ to compile it, and the results seems have not improved much. For example, It got $$\log_2(1 - \tau_k) = -26.5000000094894119\ \mathrm{for}\ k=2^{28}, 2^{29}, 2^{30}, \dots,$$ while when I used `logl(x)`, the corresponding results are $$\log_2(1 - \tau_k) = -26.5000000094894116\ \mathrm{for}\ k=2^{28}, 2^{29}, 2^{30}, \dots.$$

Comment: Note that $f(k+1)=1-e^{-f(k)}<f(k)$ for every $k$ hence $f(k)\to0$ when $k\to\infty$ and, expanding the exponential, one gets $f(k+1)=f(k)-\frac12f(k)^2+o(f(k)^2)=g(f(k))+o(f(k)^2)$ with $g(t)=\frac{2t}{2+t}$. It happens that $g$ can be iterated explicitely, leading to $g^{\circ k}(t)=\frac{2t}{2+kt}$ for every $k$, which suggests that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\, k\,f(k)=2.$$ Indeed, this result holds, as can be proven rigorously with some more care.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see. This result has also been verified by the computer program. The mathematical analysis is so powerful, it is amazing. Thank you! @Did